# generation of random covariane matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, random-matrix

in the latest book by Marcos Lopez de Prado, he provides sample code for generating a random variance-covariance matrix. He starts by generating a rectangular dataset with fewer observations than columns. The sample covariance is then not of full rank by definition. The mean of the column of the random data is 0. He then says that the sample covariance + a random diagonal matrix is now of full rank. Could you please someone explain to me the reason for the last step?

Comment: A random diagonal matrix is of full rank. If you add a random matrix, it remains of full rank.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in the explanation. The initial random matrix of data is rectangular, with more columns than obseravations. The sample covariance obtained is then not of full rank, as he also explicitly writes The adjument of summing a random diagonal matrix than should fix that according to the book, but I don't understand why this is the case

Comment: I think @Xi'an succinctly answered this in a comment so perhaps you could edit the question to say why that explanation does not satisfy you?

Comment: By considering the eigenvalues you can see why this conclusion is not true or, better, what assumption is needed to make it true.  (Counterexample: to the $1\times 1$ covariance matrix $(1)$ add the random diagonal matrix $(-1).$ The result, $(0),$ is not full rank.)